# InvalidArgumentException when trying to install a symfony flex package

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-flex

I just installed symfony and symfony flex via `composer require symfony/flex` but symfony flex aliases don't work. For example, when I try to install twig by doing `composer require twig`, I receive this answer :

Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine

[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package twig.

Did you mean one of these?
twig/twig
latte/latte
slim/twig-view
twig/extensions
twig/intl-extra

require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-scripts] [-
-update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--igno
re-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUT
OLOADER-PREFIX] [--] []...

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Did you try minimum-stability to dev in composer.json ?

Comment: No, what do I have to change in the composer.json file ?

Comment: So what motivated you to install symfony/flex?  Are you trying to update an old version of symfony?  If not then be aware the flex is installed automatically.  You really don't need to do anything.  And while I don't enjoy being unkind, I suspect that some of the other folks trying to help you don't actually know what flex is.

Comment: I want to use symfony because I don't want to write recipes myself everytime I install a package, such as annotations, twig or whatever else. Plus, I like the alias option.

Comment: Right but if you created a Symfony app using the standard procedures then flex is installed automatically.  Something like `symfony new --full my_app`.  Looks like you have something else going on.

Comment: I just did an installation with --full and the installation was longer but I'm still unable to use aliases.

Comment: What are your PHP and composer versions?  Just out of curiosity I made an empty directory and did a `composer require symfony/flex` followed by `composer require twig` and somewhat to my surprise it completed without errors.  Not sure what it actually did or how useful it would be without the framework but it did something.  I have composer 2.3.8 installed along with PHP 8.1.

Comment: The problem came from my composer version. I upgraded it and now it works fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from my composer version, once it was upgraded, the symfony flex aliases worked.